# How does JFactory::getApplication->input get the input id

Tags: component, custom-component, url, jfactory

I am trying to get the current itemid of an especific menu which calls a custom component.

I had a custom component called on the menu with the url `/something`.

Inside of the site model of my component I have this **in my constructor**:

```
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication('site')->input; 
    $uriQuery=$jinput->getArray();
    //var_dump($uriQuery);
    $itemid=$uriQuery['Itemid'];
    echo $itemid; // it gives me a random id = 234
```

If I create another menu with url `/otherthing` and call the same custom component, with the same model, the `echo $itemid` returns a differen random id = 132.

So my question is: Where does the Id comes from?. It comes from the url?. From the menú that I create?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it right. You wan't to get the ID of the current active menu.

Theres a great example on this forum: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=642224

Here's the code part:

```
// get application
$app    = JFactory::getApplication();

// get menu
$menu   = $app->getMenu();

// get active menu id
$activeId = $menu->getActive()->id;

// get active menu
$active = $menu->getActive();

// get active menu id
$activeId = $active->id;

// get active parent id 
$currentMenuParent = $active->parent_id;

// get active menu item title
$menutitle = $active->title;

// get menu item by id
$otherMenuItem = $menu->getItem( $menuID );

// get other menu item title
$title = $otherMenuItem->title;
```

**And what you want to do is this:**

```
$app   = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu  = $app->getMenu();
$id_of_your_active_menu = $menu->getActive()->id;
echo $id_of_your_active_menu;
```